# Evaluation of the integral $\int \sqrt{t^4-t^2 + 1}\,dt$

Tags: calculus, integration, trigonometry, indefinite-integrals

My friend took his Calculus $2/3$ test yesterday.

One of the questions he had trouble with was this integral:

$$\int \sqrt{t^4-t^2 + 1}dt$$

**My attempt**

It seems rather clear that the only approach was trigonometric substitution.

First, completing the square:

$$\int \sqrt{t^4-t^2 + 1}dt = \int\sqrt{t^4-t^2 + \frac{1}{4} + \frac{3}{4}}dt = \int \sqrt{\left(t^2 - \frac{1}{2}\right) + \frac{3}{4}}dt$$

Next, I let $$\sec \theta = \frac{\sqrt{\left(t^2 - \frac{1}{2}\right) + \frac{3}{4}}}{\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}}$$
$$\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\sec \theta = \sqrt{\left(t^2 - \frac{1}{2}\right) + \frac{3}{4}}$$
$$\tan \theta = \frac{t^2 - \frac{1}{2}}{\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}} = \frac{2t^2 - 1}{\sqrt{3}}$$
$$\sec^2 \theta d\theta = \frac{4}{\sqrt{3}}tdt,\ dt = \frac{\sqrt{3}\sec^2 \theta}{4t} d\theta$$
$$t = \sqrt{\frac{1}{2}\left(\sqrt{3}\tan \theta + 1\right)}$$

---

Substituting this all in:

$$\int \left(\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2} \sec \theta\right) \frac{\sqrt{3}\sec^2 \theta}{4\sqrt{\frac{1}{2}\left(\sqrt{3}\tan \theta + 1\right)}} d\theta$$

How would I approach this from here?

I'm thinking of using u-substitution but I'm sure that it would bring me back to where I started, meaning I would have to use trig. substitution again.

Comment: This looked pretty unmanageable, and WolframAlpha gives an answer involving elliptic integral functions, so presumably there is no elementary closed form. Perhaps the problem was (intended to be) $\int \sqrt{t^4 - 2 t^2 + 1} \,dt$ or something similar?

Comment: @Travis If that is the case, then maybe there is no closed form. It seemed to me that there would be.

Comment: I know that you can use euler substitution when you got $\sqrt(at^2+bt+c)$, maybe there is some way you can use euler substitution on this?

Also I think it is going to be $(t^2-\frac{1}{2})^2$ instead of $(t^2-\frac{1}{2})$

Comment: You forgot to raise your quantity $$\left(t^2-\frac{1}{2}\right)$$ to a power of two.

Answer (score 3):

The indefinite integral [cannot](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liouville's_theorem_(differential_algebra)) be [expressed](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Risch_algorithm) in terms of elementary functions. Evaluating it requires knowledge of [elliptic integrals](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_integral). However, it is interesting to note that its definite counterpart, when evaluated over the entire real line, and subtracted from its quadratic or parabolic asymptote, yields

$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty\bigg[\sqrt{t^4-t^2+1}-\bigg(t^2-\dfrac12\bigg)\bigg]dt~=~\dfrac23K\bigg(\dfrac34\bigg)+\dfrac43E\bigg(\dfrac34\bigg),$$

which is nothing else than the volume of the [oloid](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oloid), whose decimal expansion can be found on [OEIS](http://oeis.org/A215447)